# Makefile: Error during make

Tags: linux, makefile

I have the following two makefiles:

Makefile1:

```
SUBDIRS = src
SDIRS=src
TOP?=.. 
RECURSIVE_MAKE= [ -n "$(SDIRS)" ] && for i in $(SDIRS) ; do \
            (cd $$i && echo "making $$target in $(DIR)/$$i..." && \
            $(MAKE) -e TOP=$(TOP)/.. $$target INCLUDES='$(INCLUDES)') || exit 1; \
        done;

subdirs:
    @target=all; $(RECURSIVE_MAKE)

all: subdirs

include $(BUILD_TOP)/build_control/symstream/subdirs.mk
```

Makefile2 (subdirs.mk):

```
#   This is a stand-alone file to distribute targets to
#   sub-directories. Include this file alone.  

#  Make bug: It loses track of if/endif over a $(eval) call.
ifndef __subdirs_include
__subdirs_include = yes

#   This only works for the standard targets defined in $(TARGETS)
#   in utils.mk. However this list can be extended with +=.

install:: install-hdrs 

include $(BUILD_TOP)/build_control/symstream/utils.mk
include $(BUILD_TOP)/build_control/symstream/platform.mk

#  This creates a recursion rule for each pair of target and subdirectory.
#  The target for doing T in directory D is named T+D. 
#  If there is a "$(D_needs) = subdirs" then the subdirs become prerequisites
#  of D.
define __target_subdir
.PHONY:: $(1)+$(2)
$(1)+$(2) :: $(3); +$(MAKE) -C $(2) $(1)
endef

$(foreach t,$(TARGETS),\
    $(foreach d,$(strip $(SUBDIRS) $(SUBDIRS_y)),\
    $(eval $(call __target_subdir,$(t),$(d),$(patsubst %,$(t)+%,$($(d)_needs))))))

$(foreach t,$(TARGETS),\
    $(foreach d,$(strip $(SUBDIRS) $(SUBDIRS_y)),$(eval $(t)::$(t)+$(d))))


endif # __subdirs_include
```

I am getting the following error when Makefile1 is executed:

```
subdirs.mk:30: *** target file `all' has both : and :: entries.  Stop.
```

Could someone please help with this?

Comment: Can you post `subdirs.mk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post `subdirs.mk` to be sure, but seems like you have ordinary and double-column 
rules for target `all`.

From [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Double_002dColon):

> When a target appears in multiple rules, all the rules must be the
>   same type: all ordinary, or all double-colon.